# Generating alert if AWS instances stops during scheduled period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have used Instance Scheduler to start and stop the instances in different regions at specified time & its working great.
Now we want to receive an alert if the instances stops due to an issue on AWS side or if someone manually stops those during the scheduled period.

Like say our instances run between 9am to 7pm everyday from Mon-Fri. If the instance stops for any reason during this time, we want to receive an email alert.
Does AWS have service that we can use or need some other way to generate this kind of alerts?

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to create a custom solution for this for sure. If you just want to get an alert only for problems from aws side, you can configure `status check alarm` on each instance. So whenever there is an issue from aws side and your instance reachabilty is compromised, you will get a notificatuion.

Comment: Is there any way which makes the status checks to fail so that we can test this out. We had already discussed this, but don't have an idea on how to make status check fail.

Comment: You cannot check the `system status check` as it's related to hardware which is managed by `aws` while `Instance status check` is OS level. there are few ways to make it fail. 1: Corrupt the `/etc/fstab` file so that OS fails to mount the devices. 2: You can fill the disk with logs etc or make a script and make it a unit which exhaust the memory or make the cpu go 100%. Make sure to make a backup of your root device so that you can restore after the tests. I havn't myself tried any of these but I think they will work. Paolo's idea is more suitable but as I said earlier it's a custom solution.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use EventBridge to create a rule that will be triggered whenever an EC2 instance is stopped:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["EC2 Instance State-change Notification"],
  "detail": {
    "state": ["stopped"]
  }
}
```

and configure the rule to trigger a custom lambda function.
Write a lambda function that inspects the payload received as part of the invocation and that checks the time of the event. If your criteria is matched (so if the event happens outside of the 9am to 7pm window), have it so the lambda sends an email to you via SES.

Comment: Will the rule trigger even when the Instance scheduler makes the ec2 stop? Will love to have more details to get clear idea. 
Thanks!

Comment: @Archit Yes, it will trigger whenever the instance is stopped, regardless of who and how it was stopped

Comment: Would like to have the rule trigger only if the instance stops due to fault from the AWS side or someone manually stops. If we get notifications for the instance scheduler stop actions, the inbox will be cluttered by daily mails.

Comment: @Archit that's not possible

Comment: So an update - 
We were able to create a lambda function that checks status of ec2 in that particular region. 

is it possible to we use Eventbridge to apply cron on this function to check every x mins? 
also is it possible to trigger sns if cron finds any of the instance in stopped state?

Comment: @CloudWanderer Your original question was answered. Please accept my answer and open new questions